# Where does message for UPS Blocked Countries show up in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify

This is probably too specific to Shopify, but I am hoping someone else has run into something similar. So I am building a simple Shopify site I am basically finished with. We are blocking specific high fraud risk countries from being able to purchase items from our store by putting them in the list on the page Preferences->Shipping (where there are a list of countries they want blocked) each one marked as **"Rates provided by UPS (disabled)".** As Shown below:

[image]

This is the message that pops up when you try to go through the checkout process and input one of the blocked contries in the shipping form:

[image]

**MY QUESTION:**
Where is the code for this message generated, so I can edit it? I couldn't find any templates containing the words used in the message or the id's of some of the blocks used in the html that is generated. Which leads me to believe it is possibly being dynamically generated by javascript, but all the .js files seem to be libraries (not shopify js functions). I need to edit the text and link for "Shop Owner" to say "Customer Support" and link to a different page.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. This is my first time ever building anything using Shopify, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the code on the checkout pages (Javascript/HTML/...), but you change the checkout language. Using Shopify 2, you can change this setting under Settings > Checkout > Checkout Language.

If you create a custom translation you're able to translate all the messages used in the checkout. And also the *'Unfortunately there is no Shipping Rate available for your destination and/or weight of your cart.'* message.

Another approach would be to only add the countries you want to ship too. And also remove the 'rest of the world'-country. Now your checkout only lists those countries you want to ship to.

Comment: So just in case anyone doesn't know you can switch between shopify classic and Shopify 2 by adding /admin/2/enable or /admin/2/disable to your Shopify url "YourStore.myshopify.com"

So for the first answer, that would work but what I am trying to do is change what "Shop Owner" links too... So beyond just the wording I am trying to link them to a separate customer support page.

As for the second, my employer said they called shopify and they told them there was no way to remove countries from the drop down select on the checkout pages... Plus there are way more countries they are not Blocking

Comment: Well for the second part, I've tested removing all countries except one in one of my shops. The checkout page only lists that specific country.

Comment: For the "Shop Owner" links, just take a look at the translations. Just follow the links "View and customize this translation or create a new one." You can also edit the "Shop Owner" part.

Comment: Ok so if this is the line I want to change "Please contact the %s for further assistance." How would I change the %s into a link tag? can I put the html straight into the interpreter or what? I apologize for my ignorance, I am just confused how to get that to work.

Comment: I suppose you can only enter text, not HTML. But you can always try. Or contact Shopify support to see whats possible.